# get access to chart-object in highchart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

I´m not able to get access to the chart-object in highchart with the angularjs directive HIGHCHARTS-NG.

```
var chart = $scope.chartConfig.getHighcharts();

console.log("chart", chart);
```

Gives me an error: $scope.chartConfig.getHighcharts is not a function.

When I

```
console.log("chart", chartConfig);
```

the object offers me the getHighcharts()-function.

When I say

```
var chart = $scope.chartConfig
console.log("chart", chart);
```

it´s not offering the getHighCharts-function anymore!

I really need to get access to that chart-object.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I will suggest to use the highcharts libraries how they are.
Because in this case this is not an official pluggin, and the problem is that in a near future it might not be compatible anymore.

Anyway, to get the chart object you can try:

1. Using the pluggin method .getHighChart. If you have this:

`<highchart id="chart1" config="chartConfig"></highchart>`

you can use func option;

```
$scope.chartConfig = {
...,
  func: function(chart){
     //play with chart
  }
}
```

which is a reference to the callback function when it creates the highchart object:

```
var x = new Highcharts(options, func);
```

2. using jQuery

   var chart = $("#chart1").highcharts();

I hope it helps.

Regards,
Luis

Comment: highcharts api documentation: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Highcharts.charts

Comment: in fact, I want to set the Extremes of my chart, when I press a button: chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes($scope.from, $scope.to); Do you have an idea how to implement that in the func-option? Doens´t work